# Encode Json Object Data with UTF-8 in java

Tags: json, utf-8, encode

Suppose any special characters in my JSON data, they need to be encoded with UTF-8.

Example JSON:

```
String msg = { \"name\": \"SÅi®äjesh\", \"location\":\"Öslö" };
```

I tried below Scenarios

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String newString = new String(utf8Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

/* Showing ? mark symbols in my Console */

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode( original,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() ));
```

/*  Encodes the total String including {, " etc symbols.*/

Comment: It's better to share a sample of code that you wrote.  That way, people can give feedback on how it can be improved.

Comment: I tried with below scenarios. But, it encodes the whole JSON string including all characters

String json = "{ \"name\": \"SÅi®äjesh\", \"location\":\"Öslö\" }";
     System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode( json,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() ));

Answer (score 1):

Java string are UTF-16, you need to convert it to a byte array then to utf8 string.

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;

byte[] bytes = "YOUR JSON".getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
String jsonStr = new String(bytes, UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks Zaven. I tried this code. But, it shows output as ? symbols in my console